# Count rows which have timestamp preceding fixed row from the same table with specific value in fixed column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables: events and sessions.

events:

```
+-----------+---------------------+------+------------+
| event_id  |      timestamp      | flag | session_id |
+-----------+---------------------+------+------------+
| kj123123j | 2020-01-01 22:51:11 |    0 |          1 |
| j24hjk234 | 2020-01-01 21:11:00 |    0 |          1 |
| kjh234khj | 2020-01-01 21:44:17 |    1 |          1 |
| 342hj24j3 | 2020-01-01 08:11:00 |    0 |          2 |
| kk1k12323 | 2020-01-01 13:55:12 |    1 |          2 |
| 890fd8sdf | 2020-01-01 20:55:14 |    0 |          2 |
+-----------+---------------------+------+------------+
```

sessions:

```
+------------+---------+
| session_id | user_id |
+------------+---------+
|          1 | 12kk    |
|          2 | 44qj    |
+------------+---------+
```

What I want to get is a table which counts the events for each user before a flag has happened.

```
+---------+-------+
| user_id | count |
+---------+-------+
| 12kk    |     1 |
| 44qj    |     1 |
+---------+-------+
```

I tried two approaches:

1. Self join the table, which I could not test, because it was extremely slow ( the events table is enormous. )

2.

```
WITH
  events AS (
  SELECT
    events.event_id,
    events.timestamp,
    events.user_id
  FROM
    db.events events
  LEFT JOIN
    db.users users
  ON
    events.session_id = users.session_id),
  flags AS (
  SELECT
    events.event_id,
    events.timestamp
  FROM
    db.events events
  WHERE
   events.flag is TRUE )
SELECT
  events.user_id,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN events.timestamp < flags.timestamp THEN 1
    ELSE
    0
  END
    )
FROM
  flags
JOIN
  events
ON
  events.event_id = flags.event_id
GROUP BY
  events.user_id
```

The problem of the second approach is that the count column is only 0s, which definitely is not possible.

May I get some help solving this?

Comment: What if a user has multiple sessions?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd like to count the events from the previous sessions as well. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses window functions and aggregation.  However, it is not clear whether you want the counts *per session* or *per user*.  Per session, the logic loos like:

```
select user_id, countif(timestamp < timestamp_1)
from (select e.*, s.user_id
             min(case when e.flag = 1 then e.timestamp end) over (partition by e.session_id) as timestamp_1
      from events e join
           sessions s
           on s.session_id = e.session_id
     ) e
group by user_id;
```

The above counts the events before the flag *for each session*.  If you want the counts over all sessions for each user, then change the `min()` to:

```
             min(case when e.flag = 1 then e.timestamp end) over (partition by s.user_id) as timestamp_1
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon! This is exactly what I was looking for!